# invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Low Amount'

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I am trying to use `np.where` as below

`inds_2 = np.where(df2['Transaction Amount']>5000 , 'High Amount' ,'Low Amount')`

```py
> df2['Transaction Amount']
13      414
15      630
16      444
17      444
18      779
       ... 
1403     12
1404     12
1405     12
1406     12
1408    415
```

When I use  `iloc`, I get this error:

```py
> df2.iloc[inds_2]
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Low Amount'
```

I tried the function below but it did not work either:

```py
> df2['Transaction Amount'] = df2['Transaction Amount'].astype(float).astype(int)
```

Can I get some help?

Comment: Read about .iloc in documentation. It's based on integer location, not string.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably want to filter the `df2` based on high and low transactions. You can do something like this:

```py
is_high = np.where(df2['Transaction Amount']>5000 , True, False)

print("High transactions:", df2.loc[is_high])
print("Low transactions:", df2.loc[~is_high])
```

But don't forget that this is just equivalent to:

```py
df2.loc[df2['Transaction Amount']>5000]
```

The problem with `.iloc` is it's for indexing based on integer location. Check out [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html).

**Edit 1:**

```py
df2['Transaction Amount'].apply(lambda value: 'High amount' if value > 5000 else 'Low amount')
```

Comment: this maybe solved the problem partially but what if i want the values to appear as 'low amount' , 'high amount'  by np.where  and showing all data frame at the same time by iloc

Comment: Are you trying to just write high and low amount inplace of the Transaction Amount, instead of numbers?

Comment: yes what if i want to write high and low amount in place of the Transaction Amount

Comment: See edit-1 in my answer. I think that's what you want if you not insist of using numpy.